# How programming settings purchase

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-view

How to program radio button in purchase settings view when click activates module installed automatically ?

```py
class PurchaseConfig(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'purchase.config.settings'

    groupe_purchase_grouping = fields.Selection([
        (0, 'Active'),
        (1, 'Desactive')
    ], "Purchase grouping")
```

module that I can install

```py
class ProcurementOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'procurement.order'

    def _make_po_get_domain(self, partner):
        res = super(ProcurementOrder, self)._make_po_get_domain(partner)
        resr = list()
        supplier = []
        for r in res:
            if r[0] == "partner_id":
                l = ("partner_id", "=", False)
                resr.append(l)
                continue
            resr.append(r)
        resr = tuple(resr)
        return resr
```

Comment: Why did you tag this with three Odoo versions?

Comment: intersted Odoo10

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your .py

```
groupe_purchase_grouping = fields.Selection([
        (0, 'Active'),
        (1, 'Desactive')
    ], "Purchase grouping")
```

for radio button 
define in your xml :

```
<filed name ="groupe_purchase_grouping" widget ="radio"/>
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention `moduel` prefix with `your_module_name` in field name as below :

```
class PurchaseConfig(models.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'purchase.config.settings'

    module_groupe_purchase_grouping = fields.Selection([
        (0, 'Active'),
        (1, 'Desactive')
      ], "Purchase grouping")
```

Here i consider `groupe_purchase_grouping` is your module name